# Possible bug on the suggested-edits page?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I went to the [suggested edits page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) from the [approve tag wiki edits privileges page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) and it says I don't have enough privileges. It says you need at least 1500 rep, which you can see I have:

[image: suggested-edits]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were checking "greater-than" instead of "greater-than-or-equal" here.  Good catch! (;

This will be fixed with our next deploy.

Comment: Love those bugs!